# GLSurfaceView.queueEvent does not execute in the GL thread

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to execute some OpenGL commands for my GLSurfaceView from my main activity. As the OpenGL renderer works in its own thread, I have to use `queueEvent`, as far as I understand.

I'm calling `queueEvent` with the following code in my GLSurfaceView:

```
queueEvent(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
          renderer.doSomething(data); //executes some OpenGL commands
          requestRender();
}});
```

The `doSomething()` method binds a texture and compiles shaders.

This does not work. `glCreateProgram` returns `0`, which happens for example when a GL command is executed outside of the GL thread. Exactly the same code also works fine if I execute it from within my renderer. So it seems that the commands I execute using `queueEvent` are not executed within the GL context, but are executed in the wrong thread.

Is my understanding that calling `queueEvent` is sufficient to execute code inside the GL thread wrong? Is there anything else I have to do, or any mistake in how I call it now?

Comment: Does not using a `Runnable` interface pretty much imply that you want each instance of this class to run in a separate thread? `Runnable.run (...)` is the method that is called when you create a new thread.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm not sure I understand you correctly. I want to run the code inside `Runnable.run` to run in a specific thread, the GL thread. According to the [documentation of GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), queueEvent is supposed to run the Runnable in the renderer thread.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman- not in this case. A runnable is merely what you need to wrap code in, in order to pass it around for later execution. queueEvent takes that runnable, and runs it on the existing renderer thread.

Comment: FWIW, If you are not sure what thread code is running in, set a break point in it. Examine the call stack, and observe what the current thread is.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve "queueEvent takes that runnable, and runs it on the existing renderer thread" and what if my application created two renderer threads...its doable isn't it?! and if so, which one will QueueEvent chose?!

Comment: @NewbieAndCurious - No, there is only one renderer thread per surfaceview - Android creates it, not you. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/53944/45120  If you want to do significant computation that will be used to build what is rendered, you can do that in a different thread, but all GL calls for that view must be done on the provided rendering thread (after doing the expensive work on your own background thread, call `queueEvent` with data describing the result).

Comment: @NewbieAndCurious - Personally, I don't use queueEvent, because what happens when code elsewhere does another requestRender later?  That causes another draw frame, which does not know about the code and data in your queueEvent. Instead, I have a global field, an instance of my custom data class. When I'm done preparing my data, I store it in that field. Then call `requestRender`. I do all GL stuff in my draw frame method [automatically runs on render thread], which checks that field to see if it is non-null. (Don't modify the data once you've put it there; make a new set of data each time.)

Answer (score 9):

It did some experimenting and it seems that in some cases queueEvent will execute the Runnable before onSurfaceCreated is actually called, though still on the GL thread.
This can happen if you are using queueEvent immediately after onResume in the Activity.

I did the experiment with glClearColor and even though it called the command without any exceptions, the background had not changed. Maybe the GLContext is still not properly available and the commands do nothing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mad-Scientist I agree with Momchil; sounds like the code ran too early. May need to have onSurfaceCreated set a flag, and in the runnable check if that flag has been set. If it is not set, then re-queue it. Or before calling queueEvent, while still in main thread, if that flag not set, then use a Handler (declared on main thread's looper) with postDelayed to allow time to pass. Keep delaying until it is safe to call queueEvent (the flag has been set, indicating surface is created).