# Android queueEvent(new Runnable()) What if I have multiple Threads hosting Renderer?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've been reading the online documentation, and skimming through a couple of android/OpenGL books.. and it all mentioned that one way to pass or delegate event handlers calls to the GL Rendering thread is to use Android queueEvent(new Runnable(){...}) from GLSurfaceView Class.. which based on my humble java knowledge didn't make any sense..then I found this question [GLSurfaceView.queueEvent does not execute in the GL thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827048/glsurfaceview-queueevent-does-not-execute-in-the-gl-thread)
in thee comments someone confirmed my doubts by saying that calling runnable  pretty much imply that you want each instance of this class to run in a separate thread?. Yet another person said this isn't true in this particular case and that queueEvent takes that runnable, and runs it on the ***existing*** renderer thread

If the second person is right, my question is... what if I have two separate threads that execute GLRenderer... in this case which thread will execute the code that the new queueEvent(new Runnable()) host?!!
I'm so confused..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where, or how (or even why) you will start another thread that runs the code in your Renderer class, however regardless, GLSurfaceView create a thread when you call setRenderer(), and it maintain a reference to this thread.
You typically call queueEvent(new Runnable() { public void run() {             mMyRenderer.DoSomething(); }); from inside the GLSurfaceView, which has a reference to the thread it created! it doesn't matter if you have another thread that also host your rendered, it might not even visible to GLSurfaceView..
bottom-line...  queueEvent work with the thread referenced (and created) by GLSurfaceView